# What material reduces electromagnetic wave?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation

I am looking for a material that can cover an antenna to reduce electromagnetic wave. Cement reduces the wave but not a good choose in this case. Aluminium foil works too but it is too strong and blocks all waves at such a high frequency. It is better to be adjustable in thickness or number of layers. Is there any proper choose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See: http://journals.aps.org/prapplied/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevApplied.3.037001 for APS article on meta materials.
Depending on what you want see commercial quality absorbers at http://tdkrfsolutions.com/products/absorbers
Or the wiki small article on it, at  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_absorbers

Bottom line, metals will reflect most RF, and you can try tuned band absorbers or some more broadband, depending on what you want. Lower freqs will be harder, you would need thicker absorbers.

Or you could disconnect the antenna, or place filters behind it (Google RF filters), or limiters.

So, not sure what you want this to cover the antenna for, maybe get smaller antenna, plenty of devices will lower the power in/out. If you say what you are trying to do maybe we can chime in on some answer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have a wifi router whose siginal needs to be transmitted from third floor to first one. Unfortunately, it is right in front of my desk. I try to minimize the effect of the electromegnetic wave to my brian by adjusting the power of the siginal being barely enough to reach the first floor. I will try to find,some proper absorber to do that basing on the,information you provided.

Comment: I have one in my desk, from 1st to 3rd floor. About 6 ft from my head. I'm just going to get a longer cable. Didn't think much of it, and will do some simple calculations. You do realize it's not ionizing frequencies.